# How to retrieve only 100 results from a Spring JPA query?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data

I want to only retrieve 100 results from my Query using the `Spring data CrudRepository`?

For example my current query is a derieved query: `findAll()`

How can I alter this to only return `100` results and to `order` them by a certain column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, your crud repo is:

```
public interface CustomerRepository 
           extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Integer> {   

}
```

You can retrieve first 100 items using the following query:

```
Page<Customer> items = customerRepo.findAll(
    new PageRequest(1, 100, 
                new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"))));
```

The code above means that you retrieve first page with 100 items, sorted by the bean property named "id".

Comment: Best alternative way for not write new query that this already can satisfy.